# Creating table dynamically using codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to show my search output in a table using Codeigniter. Suppose if user wants to search all the volunteers of his location then the result should be shown in a table containing volunteer name,conatct no etc. Any kind of help will be realy appreciable.

Comment: I have done my searching part,means now i am getting my data from the database based on the search query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CI active record class:
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>contact</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('feild_to_search' => 'search_query'));

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->contact ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

:)